# How to replace an unknown propane lantern globe?

Tags: camping, gear-care, repairs

I have a propane lantern that the glass measures 3.25 X 3.25 and on the glass it has borosil with an r in a circle beside it, but no numbers so that we can get a new globe because it has broken.  Anyone have any idea what the number is or where I can get a new globe for it.

Comment: A picture would help to illustrate. What do you mean by "the number"?

Comment: Vote to close as unclear. without pictures this question is unanswerable.

Comment: @Horsegirl Please don't be discouraged by the close votes, just provide the additional info requested. I believe with more details this is a perfectly valid question (i.e. can and should be reopened).

Answer (score 1):

From my experience (across multiple vendors!), the glass globes on propane lanterns are fairly standard sizes.  It seems like there are two or three which are very common.  Unless you have a real odd-ball size/style (and lacking a photo or more detailed description of what you have), you should be able to pick up a replacement off the shelf at your local Walmart or Target.  Many other outdoor retailers (Academy Sports, Bass Pro Shops, Gander Mountain, etc) also carry replacements.

Take your dimensions with you to the store.  My bet is that you'll find one which is compatible.

Comment: Why not take the entire lantern (emptied of fuel) to the store?  Be 100% certain the globe will fit.